# How did Elwood know that the Illinois police force were in the audience?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-blues-brothers

In the final scene of *The Blues Brothers*, Elwood one of the blues brothers, gives the following speech:

> We're so glad to see so many of you lovely people here tonight. And we would especially like to welcome representatives of the Illinois law enforcement community, who have chosen to join us here in the Palace Hotel Ballroom at this time. We do sincerely hope that you all enjoy the show. And please remember, people, that no matter who you are, and what you do to live, thrive & survive, there are somethings that make us all the same: you, me, them...
>
> Everybody! Everybody!
>
> I mean You, You, You!

**Q. How did Elwood know that the Illinois police force were in the audience?**

Comment: It’s possible to see the audience from the stage

Answer (score 1):

He could see them from the stage.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that he could see them against the backlight, even from the stage.

[image]

[image]

Comment: In that first pic there's also an officer in the aisle directly in front of the stage cutout, and their badge is clearly visible even in a grainy dark pic.

Comment: @PaulB - Oh sure. The place is lousy with them